# How to avoid line spacing on prettier?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, prettier

Below are the code that I want it to be:

[Click here to open the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI33i.png)

Here is what it will be after I save it (refactored with prettier):

[Click here to open the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPSnU.png)

How do I configure the prettierrc to avoid only the line spacing ?

Comment: Prettier is opinionated and doesn't offer many configuration options. For more information, see their [docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy).

Comment: Can't do with ```{"printWidth": 120 }```?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.